# How to select an element in a nested HTML

Tags: html

There is a nested HTML code. How to change color of only the second h1 not writing an entire way for selection. Can I do somehow specifing a number of h1 that I want to select? We don't know how deep this a nested code is going to be so if there is a way to select it by a number, it will keep the code clean.

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Header</h1>
      <p>Paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would `body > .container > .container > h1` work for you?

Comment: @David We don't know how deeply nested this code is going to be so If we want to react a deeper element then selection will be a massive code.

Comment: But if that's the case then how will you know which element you want to target at all?

Comment: @David I meant lets say we have this code 4x nested. We need to change a color of a penultimate h1. If we write the whole way then it will not look very nice. It is gonna be a long line. I have thied to use nth-child and nth-of-type but in my case nothing worked.

Comment: In the question you state "only the second h1", did you instead mean "only the *second to last* h1"?

Comment: @David I just specified random h1 in the first place (it was the second one) because I want a universal solution that will do for any h1 that I want to get just specifying a number of this h1. I thought that there is way to use nth-child or nth-of-type that i cannot find

Comment: @КириллПопов Why not use one of the other HTML header tags like `<h2>` up to `<h6>`?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you can access it by adding a class to it.

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="second-header">Header</h1>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Header</h1>
      <p>Paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.second-header {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I cannot add a class

Comment: @КириллПопов  did you create new rules just for playing with us ?